# How to check if HTML forms are empty or not with PHP

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if there was a way to to check if html text inputs are empty, and if so, execute a certain PHP code, which I will provide.

HTML

```
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="your name" maxlength="36" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">

<input style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="your email" maxlength="36" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">

<button name="mySubmitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">subscribe</button>
```

PHP

```
if(!isset(['name']) || !isset(['email']) == 0){
        $msg_to_user = '<h1>Fill out the forms</h1>';
}
```

I was wondering if:

1. My PHP code is correct syntax, which I believe it's not
2. Is it possible to check if an input is empty, and if it is empty,
   execute a PHP code (specifically `'$msg_to_user'`)
3. It is possible to tweak my code so that when the user clicks the
   submit button, and the fields are BOTH empty, to have the
   `$msg_to_user` code execute

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your values will be in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobals, depending on your form method, ie. `method="post"`, so `if(!isset(['name']) || !isset(['email']) == 0)` should look like `if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) )`. In place of `isset()` you could also use `empty()`, which both checks if `isset()` and if the value is not empty.

Comment: @Sean Minus the `== 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `isset` check on array - `$_POST` or `$_GET` according to your HTML form method.

It should be:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="your name" maxlength="36" value="">
    <input style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="your email" maxlength="36" value="">
    <button name="mySubmitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $msg_to_user = '<h1>Fill out the forms</h1>';
} else {
    // process your results
}
```

I guess, I have answered questions A and B. What about question C - it's up to your architecture. For example, if you want to post form from page to itself (I mean `index.php` file has a form with action='index.php' or empty action), then you can do it this way (just an example approach, definitely not the best):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $msg_to_user = '<h1>Fill out the forms</h1>';
    } else {
        // do something in database
        if ($doSomethingInDatabaseSuccess)
            $msg_to_user = '<h1>Succesffully saved!</h1>'; // really? h1? :)
        else
            $msg_to_user = '<h1>Something went wrong!</h1>';
} else {
    $msg_to_user = ''; 
}

<form method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="your name" maxlength="36" value="">
    <input style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="your email" maxlength="36" value="">
    <button name="mySubmitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">subscribe</button>
</form>
<p class="result"><?php echo($msg_to_user); ?></p>
```

Comment: I have one question: Would the action="(certain url)" effect the outcome of this code? I have it set on my server to redirect the user to a different page and display the $msg_to_user depending on the integrity of the field data. i.e. if they only don't fill out the name field it will tell them to do so on the next page, but the code doesn't execute on the last suggestion you made. Every other possible outcome works except the completely empty field data.

Comment: @user3761911 If you want to work with this form in PHP, your form should have an action pointed out to this PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

A. No your syntax is off.

B. Yes

C. Yes, first you need to give your button a name property, so that it can be picked up by PHP. You also need to assign the $email and $name variables with a $_POST variable.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="your name" maxlength="36" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
<input type="email" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="your email" maxlength="36" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="mySubmitBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-md" value="subscribe">
```

PHP

```
//check to see if the submit button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['mySubmitBtn'])){
//assign the variables from the content of the input form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
  //check if name is empty
  if(!isset($name) || trim($name) ==''){
  $errorMsg = "You must enter a name";
  return;
  }
  //check if email is empty
  if(!isset($email) || trim($email) ==''){
  $errorMsg = "You must enter an email";
  return;
  }
  //do something else
```